# How to save image to external storage not save in internal

Tags: android, sd-card

i dont understand why people say that is save in external storage because when i use this code and i check in my SD CARD is not have file

Code This one

```
        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        int imageNum = 0;
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Punch");
        if(!imagesFolder.exists()){
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
        }
        String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        while (output.exists()){
            imageNum++;
            fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        }
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

when i run code and check ,It have file in "Internal Memory/Pictures/Punch/image_0.jpg"
but not see in SD CARD (SD CARD = external memory card 16 GB)
Please help me ..

Comment: Does your app ask for permissions for writing in SD card ?

Comment: Try to see what is in `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, probably there is yor local path.

Comment: use this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Hi Amit what is permissions for writing in SD card 
because i writed permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE only

Comment: this code is work fine but not save in external card (when i check in DDMS not have in external_sd but have in sdcard)

Comment: "sdcard" is the primary "external" storage directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused between what `getExternalStorageDirectory` does.

It gets the primary storage directory, specified by the the device manufacturer. This is usually "sdcard". "External_sd" as specified in your comment is infact a secondary storage directory, which will not be returned in the given method.

This is still not the protected internal storage, and can be mounted and accessed by Pcs when connected.

From android docs:

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Comment: Thank you so much everybody for suggestions It make me know more about anroid
I will be back to read more andrdoi doc.^^

Comment: @KronpatMinkwan If I answered your question, please consider marking as the accepted answer and/or upvoting. To help others in the same situation, and as thanks :)